# Master Makefile - going to directories from current path

Tags: makefile

I would like to create a `Master Makefile` from which I go to subdirectories and call other Makefiles. For this master Makefile, I did :

```
DIR_1D = $(dir $(mkfile_dir))1D
DIR_2D = $(dir $(mkfile_dir))2D
DIR_3D = $(dir $(mkfile_dir))3D

# Phony target
.PHONY: all clean

all:
        @(cd $(DIR_1D) ; $(MAKE))
        @(cd $(DIR_2D) ; $(MAKE))
        @(cd $(DIR_3D) ; $(MAKE))

# Clean target
clean:
        @(cd $(DIR_1D) ; $(MAKE) $@)
        @(cd $(DIR_2D) ; $(MAKE) $@)
        @(cd $(DIR_3D) ; $(MAKE) $@)
```

**UPDATE :** Sorry, stupid typo error, fixed, thanks

Comment: Have a look at my library for `GNU make` https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md you can use it to have master makefile and have independent makefiles in your subdirectories and at the same time have non-recursive making i.e. build stuff in parallel using `-j` switch of `GNU make`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set variables `DIR_1D`, `DIR_2D`, `DIR_3D`, but your `cd` commands use `DIR_1`, `DIR_2`, `DIR_3`. Since you didn't set those variables, you're running `cd` with no arguments, and `cd` with no arguments means `cd "$HOME"`.